# How to crop image in php based on facial recognition

Tags: php, image, crop

I want to create php code to create thumbnails of my image. But when cropping the image I will lose some important parts of the image such as faces.

Is there any packages in php to crop image on the basis of face detection etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP-Facedetection https://github.com/mauricesvay/php-facedetection should be indeed helpful.

It does the job detecting faces and provides a set of coordinates which you can ultimately use for cropping purposes:

```
// Return coordinates in JSON
// {'x':56.375, 'y':45.1, 'w':227.55}
$face_detect->toJson();

// OR

// Return coordinates as an Array
$face_detect->getFace();
```

Reference: http://www.codediesel.com/algorithms/face-detection-in-images-using-php/

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Thanks.. I have also heard about OpenCV. What about this. http://opencv-code.com/projects/web-based-interface-for-face-detection-with-opencv/

Comment: Looks like a Windows-only application. If that's not an issue for you, I guess its also a valid alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can create thumbnails of your image without cropping using [image copy resize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php#refsect1-function.imagecopyresized-examples)

Comment: Yeah.. I used crop images from the center.. I want to find out the important point of an image and after that crop from that point...

Comment: Hello Akhil, I doesn't tried this can you please find this function [image crop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php).Thanks.